# How to add params to success_url with Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I have a website where I have 3 subscription offers

Offer 1 = 4.99 euros for 30 days. (1 month)

Offer 2 = 12.99 euros for 90 days. (3 month)

Offer 3 = 23.99 euros for 180 days. (6 month)

With stripe I would like to add the right subscription duration depending on the offer chosen by the customer.

How to add a parameter to params?

I want to use it on the success method. How to "inject" `my_params` in the success_url ?

here is my controller:

```
class CheckoutController < ApplicationController
    before_action :user_logged_in?, only: [:create]

    def create
        @user = current_user
        @total = params[:total].to_d
        @session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create(
            payment_method_types: ['card'],
            line_items: [
                {
                    name: 'Rails Stripe Checkout',
                    amount: (@total * 100).to_i,
                    currency: 'eur',
                    quantity: 1
                },
            ],
            success_url: checkout_success_url + '?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
            cancel_url: checkout_cancel_url
        )
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
        end
    end

    def success
        @session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.retrieve(params[:session_id])
        @payment_intent = Stripe::PaymentIntent.retrieve(@session.payment_intent)

        @user = current_user
        if params[:my_params] == 2
            if @user.sub_lvl < 2
                @user.update(sub_lvl: 2)
            end
            if @user.end_sub_date < Time.now
                @user.update(end_sub_date: Time.now + 30.days)
            else
                @user.update(end_sub_date: end_sub_date + 30.days)
            end
        end

        if params[:my_params] == 3
            if @user.sub_lvl < 3
                @user.update(sub_lvl: 3)
            end
            if @user.end_sub_date < Time.now
                @user.update(end_sub_date: Time.now + 60.days)
            else
                @user.update(end_sub_date: end_sub_date + 60.days)
            end
        end
        
        if params[:my_params] == 4
            if @user.sub_lvl < 4
                @user.update(sub_lvl: 4)
            end
            if @user.end_sub_date < Time.now
                @user.update(end_sub_date: Time.now + 180.days)
            else
                @user.update(end_sub_date: end_sub_date + 180.days)
            end
        end
        
    end

    def cancel
        @session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.retrieve(params[:session_id])
        @payment_intent = Stripe::PaymentIntent.retrieve(@session.payment_intent)
    end

    private

    def user_logged_in?
        unless current_user
          redirect_to new_user_session_path
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: If it's just a regular route, you can pass on params as arguments: `checkout_success_url(session_id: CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID)`

Comment: I can't get this to work, I don't think I understand what to remove or what to put where

Answer (score 0):

To add params you would dynamically generate your Checkout Session [success_url](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-success_url) when you create your Checkout Session. This would require passing the necessary params to your `create` method like you do with dynamically accessing the amount.

Alternatively, you could just rely on the [amount_subtotal](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-amount_subtotal) of the Checkout Session to indicate which the Subscription plan.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand, can you please show me ?